# Hash of hash functions in cryptonite package

Tags: haskell, hash, libraries

I am trying to use the [Crypto.Hash module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.20/docs/Crypto-Hash.html) (cryptonite package) and produce "hash of hash" results.

The issue is that the signature of the module's hash function is `hashlazy :: HashAlgorithm a => ByteString -> Digest a`, so before I can produce a `hashlazy (hashlazy x)`, I'll need to translate a Digest into a ByteString.

Although there is a digestFromByteString function provided, there is no such function for the reverse (maybe it doesn't make sense for all Digests?).

So the only way I found is to do this :

```
-- produce a hexadecimal string representation of the digest
myHash :: ByteString -> String
myHash b = show (hashlazy bs :: Digest SHA256)

-- convert a hexadecimal string into a ByteString
fromHexString :: String -> ByteString
fromHexString = undefined
```

and then I can now do `hashhash x = myHash $ fromHexString $ myHash x`...

But that looks very cumbersome.

My question: Am I using the library functions properly? Did I miss a conversion function somewhere? Or should I do things differently?

=== EDIT 1 ===

I wanted to keep my question simple and avoided other details which I thought weren't important, but I do need to convert the hash result back into a ByteString, as I need to do manipulate it before hashing again. Eg,

```
-- myByteString is a constant
-- firstByteString is original input
finalResult = hash $ append myByteString (hash firstByteString)
```

=== EDIT 2 ===

I accepted ben's answer, and learned from it, but for future reference, one way to convert Crypto.Hash's `Digest a` into a `ByteString` is via the [memory package's](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.13) Data.ByteArray module and the [pack function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.13/docs/Data-ByteArray.html#v:pack) :

```
module Main where

import Data.ByteString
import Data.ByteString as BS (pack)
import Data.ByteArray (ByteArrayAccess)
import qualified Data.ByteArray as BA (unpack)
import Crypto.Hash (Digest, hash)
import Crypto.Hash.Algorithms (SHA256(..))

somehash = hash ("foo" :: ByteString) :: Digest SHA256

toByteString :: ByteArrayAccess a => a -> ByteString
toByteString = BS.pack . BA.unpack

somebytestring = toByteString somehash
```

Comment: `cryptonite` is a _cryptographic **primitive** library_ – for computing hashes from raw binary data, but it doesn't really seem to offer an interface for actually hashing Haskell values. I suppose the idea is that you should combine it with your favourite serialisation library for that purpose, e.g. [`cereal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal). There's also a [`crypto-simple`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-simple) library that seems to target applications such as yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash functions there in general require a `ByteArrayAccess` instance for their input. Only `hashlazy` in particular requires a lazy `ByteString` specifically.

`hash (hashlazy x)` should work because `Digest` has an instance of `ByteArrayAccess`. To hash multiple `Digest`s together, you can use the underlying `hashInit`/`hashUpdates`/`hashFinalize` functions, passing your all `Digest`s to `hashUpdates`.

Quick example:

```
import System.IO
import Crypto.Hash
import Crypto.Hash.Algorithms
import Data.ByteString.UTF8 as B

main = do
  putStr "Enter something to hash: " >> hFlush stdout
  line1 <- fmap B.fromString getLine
  let hash1 = hash line1 :: Digest SHA512
  putStrLn $ "First hash is " ++ show hash1
  putStr "Enter something else to hash: " >> hFlush stdout
  line2 <- fmap B.fromString getLine
  let
    ctx1 :: Context SHA512
    ctx1 = hashInit
    ctx2 = hashUpdate ctx1 hash1
    ctx3 = hashUpdate ctx2 line2
    hash2 = hashFinalize ctx3
  putStrLn $ "Second hash is " ++ show hash2
```

Gives:

```
Enter something to hash: foo
First hash is f7fbba6e0636f890e56fbbf3283e524c6fa3204ae298382d624741d0dc6638326e282c41be5e4254d8820772c5518a2c5a8c0c7f7eda19594a7eb539453e1ed7
Enter something else to hash: bar
Second hash is b612043d657248615f4c184407f4e5bfc0e6334f86056dfb641cf35ce1e33d86e5349d8e82b3b5018adb07e6b6d653d288e9ed883af624e7f34f12117a620c00
```

Verify:

```
 $ (echo -n foo | sha512sum | head -c 128 | xxd -p -r ; echo -n bar) | sha512sum
 b612043d657248615f4c184407f4e5bfc0e6334f86056dfb641cf35ce1e33d86e5349d8e82b3b5018adb07e6b6d653d288e9ed883af624e7f34f12117a620c00  -
```

Edit 2: Note that if you actually do need to manipulate the digest you get as an array of bytes, you can use the operations on the [`BytesArrayAccess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory/docs/Data-ByteArray.html#t:ByteArrayAccess) class, or convert to regular old strict `ByteString`s from there.

Comment: Thanks, that's completely correct and I should have checked but my problem is that I need to do a bit more than straight hashing a digest. For instance, I need to concatenate a given ByteString before taking the hash. Eg something like `hash (append someBstring hash firstBstring)`. I'll update my question.

Comment: You can call `hashUpdate` multiple times, once on the digest from the previous hashing and once on the extra bytestring(s).

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I understand the `hasUpdate` function properly. How should I use it to hash the contatenation of a given ByteString to the result of a previous hash? Don't I need to convert the result of the previous hash to ByteString?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example, does that help?

Comment: Works like a charm thanks. I'm also impressed with the CLI wizardry. Is it correct to say that I can use `hasUpdate` as long as I want to append ByteStrings (I meant Digests), but in case I need to do different type of manipulations (eg truncate, etc...) then I would need to convert each hash results back to an intermediary ByteString equivalent?

Comment: You can use `hashUpdate` to effectively append all kinds of byte-like things. Otherwise check out the [`ByteArrayAccess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory/docs/Data-ByteArray.html#t:ByteArrayAccess) class that `Digest`s have an instance for, they support all kinds of bytestring-like operations, and, failing that, offer a generic `convert` function that should get you a strict `ByteString`.